# How to initialize variables that contains list of tuples in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to work through this [guide](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/tensorflow-and-keras-a-beginners-tutorial-by-a-beginner-abd4c90f814f).

for this line of code, I get error:

```
model.fit(training_x, training_y, epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch=10)

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_2
     [[{{node Variable_2/read}} = Identity[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable_2)]]
```

How do I initialize a list of tuples in tensorflow?

I tried to change this line of code from:

```
training_y = tf.Variable([[0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [1],[0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0]])
```

to:

```
training_y = tf.global_variables_initializer([[0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [1],[0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0]])
```

but get error:

```
TypeError: global_variables_initializer() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

what am I doing wrong to initialize the variable?

entire code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential()

input_layer = keras.layers.Dense(3, input_shape=[3], activation='tanh')
model.add(input_layer)

output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
model.add(output_layer)

gd = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=gd, loss='mse')


training_x = tf.Variable([[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 1, 1]])
training_y = tf.Variable([[0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [1],[0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0]])



model.fit(training_x, training_y, epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch=10)
# model.save_weights('demo_model.h5')
# model.load_weights('demo_model.h5')

text_x = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 0]])
test_y = model.predict(text_x, verbose=0, steps=1)


print(test_y)
```

Updated code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential()

input_layer = keras.layers.Dense(3, input_shape=[3], activation='tanh')
model.add(input_layer)

output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
model.add(output_layer)

gd = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=gd, loss='mse')

sess = tf.Session()  #NEW LINE

training_x = tf.Variable([[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 1, 1]])
training_y = tf.Variable([[0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [1],[0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0]])

#init_op = tf.initialize_variables([training_x, training_y])
init_op = tf.initializers.global_variables()


sess.run(init_op)  #NEW LINE

model.fit(training_x, training_y, epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch=10)
# model.save_weights('demo_model.h5')
# model.load_weights('demo_model.h5')

text_x = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 0]])
test_y = model.predict(text_x, verbose=0, steps=1)

print(test_y)
```

Comment: Your code isn't the same as is on the tutorial which you've linked. Please show your actual code - it's impossible for us to tell you why this is happening but it's clear that 1) the variables aren't being initialized, and 2) `global_variables_initializer()` takes no arguments.

Comment: @IanQuah I added the entire code

Comment: Where is `var_list` coming from?

Comment: @IanQuah that was my attempt to initalize the variables I removed it in the above example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sess = tf.Session()  #NEW LINE

training_x = tf.Variable([[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 1, 1]])
training_y = tf.Variable([[0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [1],[0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0]])

init_op = tf.initialize_variables([training_x, training_y, test_x, test_y])  #NEW LINE

sess.run(init_op)  #NEW LINE

model.fit(training_x, training_y, epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch=10)
# model.save_weights('demo_model.h5')
# model.load_weights('demo_model.h5')

text_x = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 0]])
test_y = model.predict(text_x, verbose=0, steps=1)

print(test_y)
```

Hopefully that gets your through your "uninitialized variables" issue.

Basically, the issue you're running into is that TF is a wrapper around C++. So, to handle some optimization stuff, they require you to 1) define all the variables, 2) initialize them BEFORE doing any operations. Hence, you faced the issue of

```
model.fit(training_x, training_y, epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch=10)
```

giving you the "uninitialized variables" error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I removed `test_x` and `test_y` from `init_op` line. Still getting same error as above.

Comment: Also tried changing `tf.initialize_variables` to `tf.variables_initializer`, still same error.

Comment: Try [global initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/global_variables) - it's probably because now even though the variables are initialized, the models layers are not

Comment: I commented out `tf.initialize_variable` and tried `tf.initializers.global_variables()`. It got through `1/1000` epoch, but then gave me this error `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable
  [[{{node Variable/read}} = Identity[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable)]]`

Comment: After you've replaced it can you copy-paste your code into your original question?

Comment: Hmm, when I run the pasted code I get a different error. it has to do with `model.fit`, and stuff about the dimensions, not that it's uninitialized. `AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'ndim'`

Comment: Thats very weird, Ive restarted my kernal multiple times and its still the same error.

Comment: Try pasting into a text file and running that- no kept sessions or whatever

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you beyond that. I will say that now since you've done the global initializer as long as you don't define any tf variables after it, all your variables should be initialized

Comment: I fixed it! change the `tf.Variable` to `np.array`. I will accept your answer if you change it.